# Why maven ignores my JAVA_HOME?

Tags: java, maven-2

This is what I'm getting when `mvn` is executed from CruiseControl:

```
Unable to locate the Javac Compiler in:
  /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0.x86_64/jre/../lib/tools.jar
Please ensure you are using JDK 1.4 or above and
not a JRE (the com.sun.tools.javac.Main class is required).
In most cases you can change the location of your Java
installation by setting the JAVA_HOME environment variable.
```

At the same time, starting it from command line gives correct result. Why `mvn` is going into this `tools.jar`? Why it is ignoring my `JAVA_HOME`? And how can I fix it?

I don't know what are the values of `JAVA_HOME/PATH` when `mvn` is started from CC. I would really love to get this information but I don't know how. CC itself is started from user `cc` and `env` for this user gives me (it's CentOS 5.4):

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/default
PATH=/usr/local/maven/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/home/cc/bin
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have a linux machine.

1. Take a look on `/usr/bin/java`, this is a symbolic link. Look where is a target of this symbolic link (in my case the target is at this location `/etc/alternatives/java`)
2. `/etc/alternatives/java` is symbolic link too. Create new symbolic link to "proper" JVM (e.g. Sun's JVM)
3. Replace `/etc/alternatives/java` with newly created symbolic link.

This works for Ubuntu distribution. There is an automatic way how to do that but I forgot it actually :D

Comment: This is the way: `/usr/sbin/alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /usr/java/latest/bin/java 2`?

Answer (score 11):

I had the same problem and a simple re-install of Java JDK solved it for me:

**`apt-get install openjdk-6-jdk`**

Answer (score 2):

> Why mvn is going into this tools.jar?

Because `tools.jar` contains the `com.sun.tools.javac.Main` class which is used to invoke the `javac` compiler programmatically.

> Why it is ignoring my JAVA_HOME

That's the "interesting" part (since it's working outside CC). Are you running CC with a dedicated user? If yes, is `JAVA_HOME` well defined for this user? What is the output of

```
echo $JAVA_HOME -or-
echo $PATH
```

Comment: I just updated my question with the information you asked. Everything works fine outside of CC..

Answer (score 0):

type the following line to the version of Sun

```
sudo update-java-alternatives -s java-6-sun
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up having to point to the Oracle Java 7 installations on Ubuntu.  Gradle (1.6) does not seem to like sym links at all.  So I edited the /opt/gradle/gradle-1.6/bin/gradle file to export a JAVA_HOME of /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle at the top of the script.  It's happy now.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is far outdated question, but I ended up there googling the same problem.
So this solution also works fine: just put "fork='yes'" in "javac" task. After this javac task become honoring the JAVA_HOME setting.

Answer (score 0):

Also have a look if you have a `~/.mavenrc` file. Here you can override the system `$JAVA_HOME`. And when the value in the `~/.mavenrc` points to an invalid path, you also get the warning. Took me hours to figure that out...