# how to change java path for maven

Tags: java, maven-2, mahout

I'm trying to compile the mahout using maven2, but there's an error:
"Embedded error: tools.jar not found: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-i386/jre/../lib/tools.jar"
So I think if I change the path from jre to jdk, tools.jar will be found. 
But the question is how to change the path for maven2?
Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: I assume you should change `JAVA_HOME` env variable.

Comment: Actually, I can use update-alternative to update the path.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution in another thread:  [Why maven ignores my JAVA_HOME?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3350722/why-maven-ignores-my-java-home)

Reinstalling jdk worked for me as well: 
sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jdk

Answer (score 1):

You will need both  Java JDK and JRE.

${java.home} specifies the path to the current JRE_HOME environment use with relative paths to get for example: ${java.home}../bin/java.exe

And with a JDK for example in c:\jdk the maven ${java.home} is pointing to c:\jdk\jre

Comment: I think if you install JDK, you automatically have jre.